# Jmeter - Json Path extractor - conditional selection

Tags: json, jmeter

I'm trying to conditionally extract the value of an element from the following sample json response:

```
{
    "books": [
    {
        "title": "book 1 title",
        "author": {
            "firstName": "author01",
            "lastName": "abc"
        }
    }
    {
       "title": "book 2 title",
       "author": {
          "firstName": "author02",
          "lastName": "xyz"
       }
    }
   ]
}
```

I want to select the book title where lastName == xyz. Here the expression that I use:
$.books[?(@.author.lastName=='xyz')]

but it returns []

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Your JSON Path expression is correct, demo:

[image: JSON Path Conditional Select]

however there is a problem with your JSON:

```
{
  "books": [
    {
      "title": "book 1 title",
      "author": {
        "firstName": "author01",
        "lastName": "abc"
      }
    }, <-----------------------------you need the comma here
    {
      "title": "book 2 title",
      "author": {
        "firstName": "author02",
        "lastName": "xyz"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

If your response cannot be resolved to a valid JSON - you will have to use [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) instead. If it is - double check your JSON Path expression and also worth checking out [JMeter's JSON Path Extractor Plugin - Advanced Usage Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter)

Comment: @Dimitri, my bad. I forgot the comma. Also I meant my expression is $.books[?(@.author.lastName=='xyz')].title (sorry about repeating but I can't edit my question. don't know why). Here's what my thinking for my expression:
1. $.books --> get an array of book
2. ?() --> fileter
3. ?(@.author.lastName=='xyx') ----> pick author object's lastname and compare with xyz. However, it doesn't work. Looks like ?() only can take the first level object. IOW ?(@.title=='book 2 title') is fine.
Anyways, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try below expression:

$.books[?(@.author.lastName=='xyz')].title